# How to put hive table on complex nested XML file

Tags: hive, xmlserde

I am trying to create a hive table on top of a complex XML file using hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar.  I can get it to work for XML in the examples on the internet, but I can't get it to work for my XML file which seems to be more complex than the examples I have found online.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SSNExportDocument xmlns="urn:com:ssn:schema:export:SSNExportFormat.xsd" Version="0.1" DocumentID="eef9c8c5-0fc5-485b-bf05-7324917a7f5e-2" ExportID="eef9c8c5-0fc5-485b-bf05-7324917a7f5e" JobID="164771" RunID="3456662" CreationTime="2019-07-29T13:15:09.584-05:00" StartTime="2019-07-29T09:15:00.000-05:00" EndTime="2019-07-29T13:15:00.000-05:00">
    <MeterData MeterName="50000010" UtilDeviceID="50000010" MacID="a0:06:5f:00:00:00:00:0a">
        <IntervalReadData IntervalLength="15" StartTime="2019-07-29T08:00:00.000-05:00" EndTime="2019-07-29T12:00:00.000-05:00" NumberIntervals="16">
            <Interval EndTime="2019-07-29T08:15:00.000-05:00" GatewayCollectedTime="2019-07-29T12:06:46.302-05:00" BlockSequenceNumber="181" IntervalSequenceNumber="29">
                <Reading Channel="20" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3.3750" UOM="kWh(del)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="30" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3375.0000" UOM="kWh(rec)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="101" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="V Ph(A-N)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="102" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="V Ph(B-N)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="103" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="I A max" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="104" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="I B max" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="50" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3.3750" UOM="kVARh(del)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
            </Interval>
            <Interval EndTime="2019-07-29T08:30:00.000-05:00" GatewayCollectedTime="2019-07-29T12:06:46.302-05:00" BlockSequenceNumber="181" IntervalSequenceNumber="30">
                <Reading Channel="20" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3.3750" UOM="kWh(del)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="30" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3375.0000" UOM="kWh(rec)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="101" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="V Ph(A-N)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="102" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="V Ph(B-N)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="103" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="I A max" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="104" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="I B max" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="50" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3.3750" UOM="kVARh(del)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
            </Interval>         
        </IntervalReadData>
    </MeterData>
    <MeterData MeterName="50000022" UtilDeviceID="50000022" MacID="a0:06:5f:00:00:00:00:16">
        <IntervalReadData IntervalLength="15" StartTime="2019-07-29T08:00:00.000-05:00" EndTime="2019-07-29T12:00:00.000-05:00" NumberIntervals="16">
            <Interval EndTime="2019-07-29T08:15:00.000-05:00" GatewayCollectedTime="2019-07-29T12:06:49.324-05:00" BlockSequenceNumber="181" IntervalSequenceNumber="29">
                <Reading Channel="20" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3.3750" UOM="kWh(del)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="30" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3375.0000" UOM="kWh(rec)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="101" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="V Ph(A-N)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="102" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="V Ph(B-N)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="103" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="I A max" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="104" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="I B max" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="50" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3.3750" UOM="kVARh(del)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
            </Interval>
            <Interval EndTime="2019-07-29T08:30:00.000-05:00" GatewayCollectedTime="2019-07-29T12:06:49.324-05:00" BlockSequenceNumber="181" IntervalSequenceNumber="30">
                <Reading Channel="20" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3.3750" UOM="kWh(del)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="30" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3375.0000" UOM="kWh(rec)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="101" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="V Ph(A-N)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="102" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="V Ph(B-N)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="103" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="I A max" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="104" RawValue="5625.0" Value="399.9999" UOM="I B max" BlockEndValue="0"/>
                <Reading Channel="50" RawValue="5625.0" Value="3.3750" UOM="kVARh(del)" BlockEndValue="0"/>
            </Interval>
        </IntervalReadData>
    </MeterData>
</SSNExportDocument>
```

I first found example code on http://dennysjymbo.blogspot.com/2018/05/using-xml-serde-in-hive-for-exploding.html which works fine, so I know that the serde is being found in the class path.

I've tried countless ways to define the table.

This is my latest attempt:

```
drop table if exists default.xmltest;
create external table default.xmltest(
         MeterData array<
           struct<MeterData:array<
             struct<MeterName:string,UtilDeviceID:string,MacID:string,
               IntervalReadData:struct<IntervalLength:string,StartTime:string,EndTime:string,NumberIntervals:string, 
                 Interval:array<
                   struct<EndTime:string,GatewayCollectedTime:string,BlockSequenceNumber:string,IntervalSequenceNumber:string, 
                     Reading:array<
                       struct<Channel:string,RawValue:string,Value:string,UOM:string,BlockEndValue:string
>>>>>>>>>)
     row format serde 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
     with serdeproperties ("column.xpath.MeterData" = "/SSNExportDocument/MeterData")
     stored as inputformat 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
     outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
     location "/user/cyelve1/xmltest"
     tblproperties ( "xmlinput.start" = "<SSNExportDocument>" ,"xmlinput.end" = "</SSNExportDocument>" );
```

NOTE: If I try to use the start tag that has attributes like I have seen in other examples like so:

```
tblproperties ( "xmlinput.start" = "<SSNExportDocument " ,"xmlinput.end" = "</SSNExportDocument>" )
```

I get a NULL returned.  So, just for testing I changed the start tag

```
FROM

<SSNExportDocument xmlns="urn:com:ssn:schema:export:SSNExportFormat.xsd" Version="0.1" DocumentID="eef9c8c5-0fc5-485b-bf05-7324917a7f5e-2" ExportID="eef9c8c5-0fc5-485b-bf05-7324917a7f5e" JobID="164771" RunID="3456662" CreationTime="2019-07-29T13:15:09.584-05:00" StartTime="2019-07-29T09:15:00.000-05:00" EndTime="2019-07-29T13:15:00.000-05:00">

TO

<SSNExportDocument>
```

I am expecting a result like the one that worked in the example I used from the http://dennysjymbo.blogspot.com/2018/05/using-xml-serde-in-hive-for-exploding.html site:

```
[{"customerleveldata":{"survey_id":144434840,"client_id":6780,"service":"HH","recdate":"2018-04-02","disdate":"2018-01-01","analysis":[{"response":{"varname":"B2PR","value":"5"}},{"response":{"varname":"PI2PR","value":"5"}}],"demographics":[{"response":{"varname":"AGE","value":"90"}},{"response":{"varname":"CMSH_1","value":"Yes"}}],"hcahps":[{"response":{"varname":"CMSH_10","value":"Yes"}},{"response":{"varname":"CMSH_12","value":"Yes"}}]}}]
```

but this is my result:

```
[{"meterdata":[{"metername":null,"utildeviceid":null,"macid":null,"intervalreaddata":{"intervallength":null,"starttime":null,"endtime":"<string>2019-07-29T08:15:00.000-05:002019-07-29T08:30:00.000-05:00</string>","numberintervals":null,"interval":[{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]}]}}]},{"meterdata":[{"metername":null,"utildeviceid":null,"macid":null,"intervalreaddata":{"intervallength":null,"starttime":null,"endtime":"<string>2019-07-29T08:15:00.000-05:002019-07-29T08:30:00.000-05:00</string>","numberintervals":null,"interval":[{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]},{"endtime":null,"gatewaycollectedtime":null,"blocksequencenumber":null,"intervalsequencenumber":null,"reading":[]}]}}]}]
```